# How can I make this animation in Android smoother?

Tags: android, animation, graphics, translate

I'm currently writing an android app which includes a musical tuner. A bar moves back and forth across the tuner to indicate how sharp or flat the person played a note. The code I'm currently using to move the bar is as follows:

```
    public void moveBar(int newBarPosition) {
    currentlyAnimating = true;
    final ImageView tuningBar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tuner_bar);
    final Animation barAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(currentBarPos, newBarPosition, 0, 0);
    barAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    barAnimation.setDuration(50);
    currentBarPos = newBarPosition;


        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                tuningBar.startAnimation(barAnimation);
                Thread.sleep(50);
                    currentlyAnimating = false;
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

The animation needs to be short as a reading for the pitch of the sound from the instrument is made approximately every 10 milliseconds or so. This leads to a very jumpy animation.

I have access to all of the points the bar needs to be moved to before the animations are played as the tuner is showing the pitch of a recorded note, so my question is: Is there anyway I can make this animation smoother? Are there other types of animation in android which are more suitable for a large amount of new points for a drawable to be moved to over a short amount of time?

Comment: first of all get rid of `Thread.sleep(50);` ... every time when you are using `Thread.sleep` small kitten dies ... but if you are doing this on main thread then 10 tiny, fluffy, kittens die ... please, stop killing kittens

Comment: @Selvin it is not true: when in "non UI" thread, `Tread.sleep()` does not kill any kittens

Comment: @Selvin Haha ok I'll remove it. The reason it's there is because some times between MoveBar() calls can be less than 50ms which lead to animations waiting till the current animation was finished to execute, causing the animations to desync with the audio that's play along with the animation. I tried to solve the problem by using a lock of sorts (currentlyAnimating) which the method aquires, then the thread sleeps for 50ms and then releases the lock.